# How to implement a standard-compliant assert macro with an optional formatted message?

Tags: c++, macros, assert

What's the way to implement a standard-compliant assert macro with an optional formatted message?

What I have works in clang, but (correctly) triggers the `-Wgnu-zero-variadic-macro-arguments` warning if it is turned on (e.g. via `-Wpedantic`) when the macro is used without the optional message. [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ai21vC0idTkwZkV6)

```
#define MyAssert(expression, ...)                                      \
    do {                                                               \
        if(!(expression))                                              \
        {                                                              \
            printf("Assertion error: " #expression " | " __VA_ARGS__); \
            abort();                                                   \
        }                                                              \
    } while(0)
```

Comment: `assert(expression && "Bad!")`?

Comment: @StoryTeller But that doesn't support inline formatting of the error message.

Comment: Yeah. True. The `...` isn't optional though. We'll need to work around it.

Comment: @StoryTeller I know - that's the source of the question :) How to implement this in a standard-compliant way.

Comment: Do you have access to C++17?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher In some projects. A C++17-based solution would be appreciated in any case, regardless of whether I could use it right now in production.

Comment: Is variadic templates suitable for you?

Comment: @DmytroDadyka I would be interested in seeing a solution based on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution which I'm not particularly proud of..

We can obtain the first argument in plain form and as a string using:

```
#define VA_ARGS_HEAD(N, ...) N
#define VA_ARGS_HEAD_STR(N, ...) #N
```

Note that in usage, in order to not get warnings, you should do `VA_ARGS_HEAD(__VA_ARGS__, )` (with the extra `,`) so that `VA_ARGS_HEAD` is never used with a single parameter (trick taken from [StoryTeller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53986816/40916)).

We define the following helper function:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

inline int assertionMessage(bool, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    int r;
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    r = vprintf(fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    return r;
}
```

When the assertion has a format string, the function would work with `__VA_ARGS__` as is, however when the `bool` is the only argument, we're missing a format string. That's why we'll add another empty string after `__VA_ARGS__` when invoking it:

```
#define MyAssert(...)                                                          \
    do {                                                                       \
        if(!(VA_ARGS_HEAD(__VA_ARGS__, )))                                     \
        {                                                                      \
            printf("Assertion error: %s | ", VA_ARGS_HEAD_STR(__VA_ARGS__, )); \
            assertionMessage(__VA_ARGS__, "");                                 \
            abort();                                                           \
        }                                                                      \
    } while(0)
```

Note that `assertionMessage` doesn't have `printf` in its name. This is deliberate and intended to avoid the compiler giving format-string related warnings for its invocations with the extra `""` argument. The down-side for this is that we don't get the format-string related warnings when they are helpful.

Answer (score 4):

One needs to really use the preprocessor to the max in order to differentiate no additional arguments from the case where they are present. But with Boost.PP one can do this:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/variadic/size.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/sub.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/logical/bool.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp>


#define MyAssert(...) BOOST_PP_CAT(MY_ASSERT,BOOST_PP_BOOL(BOOST_PP_SUB(BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__), 1)))(__VA_ARGS__)

#define MY_ASSERT0(expr) MY_ASSERT1(expr,)

#define MY_ASSERT1(expression, ...)                                    \
    do {                                                               \
        if(!(expression))                                              \
        {                                                              \
            std::printf("Assertion error: " #expression " | " __VA_ARGS__); \
            std::abort();                                              \
        }                                                              \
    } while(0)
```

`MyAssert` must accept at least one argument (standard). Then we count the arguments, subtract one, and turn to a boolean (0 or 1). This 0 or 1 is concatenated to the token `MY_ASSERT` to form a macro name, to which we proceed to forward the arguments.

`MY_ASSERT1` (with args), is your original macro. `MY_ASSERT0` substitutes itself with `MY_ASSERT1(expr,)`, the trailing comma means we pass another argument (thus fulfilling the requirement for the one extra argument), but it is an empty token sequence, so it does nothing.

You can [see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1cfefe3e394b5fbe).

---

Since we already went down this rabbit hole, if one doesn't want to pull in Boost.PP the above can be accomplished with the usual argument counting trick, slightly adapted. First, we must decide on a maximum limit for the arguments we allow. I chose 20, you can choose more. We'll need the typical `CONCAT` macro, and this macro here:

```
#define HAS_ARGS(...) HAS_ARGS_(__VA_ARGS__,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,)
#define HAS_ARGS_(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,e, N, ...) N
```

It's argument counting, but with a twist. When `__VA_ARGS__` is a single argument (no extra ones), the `N` resolved as 0. Otherwise, it is resolved as 1. There can be up to 20 extra arguments after the expression, any number of which will resolve to the same 1. Now we just plug it into the same place we used boost before:

```
#define MyAssert(...) CONCAT(MY_ASSERT, HAS_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__))(__VA_ARGS__)
```

[You can tinker with it here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/444b6a0dc3467181)

Comment: While this solution is more complex than @yairchu 's, it has the advantage of allowing to annotate `assertionMessage` with `__attribute__((__format__ (__printf__, 2, 3)))` to get helpful warnings about mistakes about invalid string formats and parameters combinations passed to the assertion macro. With @yairchu's answer, adding the attribute results in `-Wformat-extra-args` warnings due to the extra `""` passed into `assertionMessage`.

Comment: This seems to work incorrectly in Visual Studio. The passed `__VA_ARGS__` to `MY_ASSERT1` are passed as a single argument!

Comment: @yairchu - `__VA_ARGS__` being a single amaglamtion of the remaining tokens (with commas) is standard. Not discounting the possibility of a MSVC bug, but your comment isn't too informative.

Comment: @StoryTeller I meant that all of `__VA_ARGS__` with a parentheses around it becomes `expression` in `MY_ASSERT1`, where the intention was only for the single argument to be `expression` and the rest to be `MY_ASSERT1`'s `__VA_ARGS__`.

Comment: @yairchu - Well then, *definitely* a MSVC bug. It may or may not be possible to solve it with another layer of indirection. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

The basic solution is to use `<<` on cerr:

```
#define MyAssert(expression, msg)                                  \
do {                                                               \
    if(!(expression))                                              \
    {                                                              \
        std::cerr << msg;                                          \
        abort();                                                   \
    }                                                              \
} while(0)
```

This solution uses C++ streams, so you can format the output as you see fit. Actually this is a simplification of a C++17 solution that I'm using to avoid temporaries (people tend to use `+` instead of `<<` with this solution, triggering some efficiency warnings).

Use it then like this:

```
MyAssert(true, "message " << variable << " units");
```

I think the optionality is bogus here, as you are outputting "Assertion error:" meaning that you expect a message.

Comment: Thanks! The optionality is not bogus, as sometimes there is no extra useful context to add to the failed expression. Note the failed expression is *always* printed, following the colon. You might say that the optionality is bogus because I'm also printing `|` - but that may be replaced with a space, or, if one wishes, make a more complicated macro which only prints it if `__VA_ARGS__` is not empty (though it should never be empty according to the standard :))

Comment: Oh yes, my bad... In that case, you can use @StoryTeller's trick to pass `#expression` as the second argument to `MyAssert`.