# Conforming way to handle varargs in macro function

Tags: c, macros, variadic-functions

I'm trying to understand how to handle varargs in a macro function conformingly (i.e. avoiding `gcc`'s comma swallowing `##__VA_ARGS__`). I wrote this:

```
#define IS_DEFINED(ARG) strlen(#ARG)
#define FOO(a, ...) \
    if(IS_DEFINED(__VA_ARGS__)){\
        printf(#a, __VA_ARGS__)\
    } else {\
        printf(#a)\
    }
```

But it does not generate a valid program test. `FOO(1)` expands to

```
if(strlen("")){ printf("1", ) } else { printf("1") };
```

which does not compile.

Is there a way to handle a case of vararg macro function with one parameter and vararg?

Comment: This is for C++, but the idea is the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53986620 .

Comment: @StoryTeller It's kindof offtop, buy may I ask you the reason to use `do{}while(0)` construction in the replacement list? Why doesn't a simple block `{ }` do the job?

Comment: It's for the semi-colon at the end. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-use-apparently-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-macros

Comment: See the discussion in [C `#define` macro for debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644868/c-define-macro-for-debug-printing/1644898#1644898)

Answer (score 1):

[From C23 onwards](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3033.htm), you should be able to use `__VA_OPT__()` for this:

```
#define FOO(a, ...) \
        printf(#a __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__)
```